# HTML formatting issue, is it because of hyphen in numeric data?

Tags: html

I am successfully triggering / sending an email with TABLE data by writing an HTML code in my program, well.

But I have a small formatting issue, as below,

1st column in the table is 'Project ID': 
Project ID data example is as 2013-100123, I mean, all are numbers except hyphen
The Project ID data is coming in 2 lines, but I want all in one line, I mean, no splitting. I guess, this is because of HYPHEN in numeric data! Because in the 2nd column of my table the - Project Name data also has a HYPHEN but not splitting! Its example data is as 'My-Project Name is Test'

Currently it's splitting / showing up as below

```
2013-
100123
```

Just for testing I changed from HYPHEN to a alphabet in Project ID data as below, then its (i mean, coming in just one line) fine,

```
2013A100123
```

Please let me know how can I fix my issue (getting all the Project ID data / 1st column data in same /single row) no splitting?

Comment: Change the style to white-space:nowrap;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always define the width of the column to be long enough to fit in the hyphened content, this way it will stay on one line and not split.

Comment: Thanyk you Stevenson.

if you get a chance, pls. let me know the code snippet for specifying the column width in the table via HTML in outlook emial for explorer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your table column is very narrow. The lines of text are wrapped around at the line-end. You could set the CSS property `white-space: nowrap;` to avoid the line break at hyphens.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space